# Split dictionaries into different dictionaries based on the key in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary:

```
d = {'a_c':1,'b_c':2,'a_d':3,'b_d':4}
```

how do I split into two based on the last word/letter of the key ('c','d') like this?

```
d1 = {'a_c':1,'b_c':2}
d2 = {'a_d':3,'b_d':4}
```

Comment: A dictionary cannot have the same key `a_d`

Comment: Did you intend for the second ``a_d`` to actually be ``b_d``?

Comment: @Marc oops I miss typed it.EDited it now

Comment: yes @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = {'a_c':1,'b_c':2,'a_d':3,'b_d':4}

key = lambda s: s.split('_')[1]
res = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in d.items():
  res[key(k)][k] = v

print(list(res.values()))
```

Output:

```
[{'a_c': 1, 'b_c': 2}, {'a_d': 3, 'b_d': 4}]
```

The result is a list of dictionaries divided on the last letter of the key.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
func = lambda ending_str: {x: d[x] for x in d.keys() if x.endswith(ending_str)}
d1 = func('_c')
d2 = func('_d')
```

Also, like [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65841734/split-dictionaries-into-different-dictionaries-based-on-the-key-in-python/65841931#comment116412932_65841734) mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't have two same name keys in the dictionary. It will only keep the last key/value pair in that case.

Comment: thank you. Is there any other function which automatically divides the dictionary based on the last element of the key?